Understanding of KL divergence
I am learning machine learning and encountered KL divergence:
$$
\int p(x) \log\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right) \, \text{d}x
$$
I understand that this measure calculates the difference between two probability distributions. I have written down the formula as follows (where $p(x)$ is the true distribution and $q(x)$ is the approximated distribution):
$$
\int p(x) \log\left(\frac{1}{q(x)}\right) \, \text{d}x - \int p(x) \log\left(\frac{1}{p(x)}\right) \, \text{d}x
$$
I understand this formula as the difference between the entropy of the approximated distribution and the entropy of the true distribution.
The question is: why do we multiply the entropy of the approximated distribution by $p(x)$ instead of $q(x)$?

Are you asking why the Kullback-Leibler divergence is defined the way it is? It doesn’t rely on one distribution being true and the other an approximation. Also: MathJax.

Maybe here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90537/what-is-the-motivation-of-the-kullback-leibler-divergence

It is measuring the average effect of using $q$ when $p$ is the "right" distribution, relative to the effect of using $p$ when $p$ is the "right" distribution. Exactly what is meant by "effect" and "right" depends on which of many interpretations is given to the KL divergence.  In all cases, this results in a nonnegative value.

Thanks all for reply.
